# Calculation of Longitude and Latitude of a Point which is about 'x' mts in 'y' direction

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I want to calculate the Longitude and Latitude of a point or an object which is about x meters(approximately) in some direction. I know the Longitude and Latitude of my current location. I want to calculate the longitude and latitude of the object. Is it possible to calculate ? If yes how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you're going for a rough answer. That's good because if you want accuracy and precision it gets complicated fast. You know that the planet is not a sphere. You might not realize that it's also significantly different from an oblate spheroid, even when it's good enough to imagine that everything is at "sea level". This non-spheroidal shape is called the geoid.

Comment: @minopret: Well thats what I wanted. I can still get the accurate Longitude and Latitude if I find the correct calculation method.

Comment: Another website for more information: http://www.geomidpoint.com/destination/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to calculate.  See the section **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point** at this website: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html